# Intel OpenGL Driver bug?

Tags: opengl, glsl, driver

Whenever I try to render my terrain with point light's it only works on my Nvidia gpu and driver, and not the Intel integrated and driver. I believe the problem is in my code and a bug in the Nvidia gpu since I heard Nvidia's OpenGL implementations are buggy and will let you get away with things your not supposed to. And since I get no error's I need help debugging my shader's.

**Link:**
http://pastebin.com/sgwBatnw

**Note:**
I use OpenGL 2 and GLSL Version 120

### **Edit:**

I was able to fix the problem on my one, to anyone with similar problems it's not because I used the regular transformation matrix because when I did that I set the normals w value to 0.0; The problem was that with the intel integrated graphics there is apparently a max number of array's in a uniform or max uniform size in general and I was going over that limit but it was deciding not to report it. Another thing wrong with this code was that I was doing implicit type conversion (dividing vec3's by floats) so I corrected those things and it started to work. Here's my updated code.

Link: http://pastebin.com/zydK7YMh

Comment: A bit of terminology: A driver is buggy if it violates the specification or makes your program crash. NVidia's driver takes some leeway in interpreting the specification in certain corner cases, but it's not really buggy in that sense. But yes, it's quite possible that NVidia's driver is forgiving some mistake on your end.

Comment: One thing (probably unrelated to your problem): Surface normals are not transformed by the regular modelview matrix, but by the transposed inverse of the modelview matrix. As long as you don't have some (nonuniform) scaling in your T matrix your code should work in that regard.

Comment: I'll correct my model view matrix right away

Comment: Your modelview matrix is not wrong, but you must not apply it to normals. Normals need a different matrix derived from the modelview matrix.